# iframe is not loaded in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer

### My code:

```
async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();

   await page.goto('https://example.com' , {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
   }); 

   await page.screenshot({path: 'home.png', fullPage: true});
   let frames = await page.frames();
   await page.screenshot({path: 'home.png', fullPage: true});
   var iFrame = frames.find(f => f.url().indexOf("https://accounts.") > -1);
   const usernameInput = await iFrame.waitForSelector("[name=username]" , {visible : true});
   await usernameInput.type(email);
   const passwordInput = await iFrame.waitForSelector("[name=password]" , {visible : true});
   await passwordInput.type(password);
   const navigationPromisePortal = page.waitForNavigation();
   await iFrame.click(".primary");
   await navigationPromisePortal;
   var cookies = await page.cookies();
   await browser.close();

   return cookies;
}
```

I'm trying to get cookies from example.com. But every time it accounts `iFrame` is not loaded. This page is built by react. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the actual error message that you are receiving?

Comment: iFrame is undefined